# Perl socket programming problems after continuous write to socket

Tags: perl, tcp, sockets

I am using `IO::Socket::INET` to create socket like this:

```
$lsn1 = IO::Socket::INET->new(
                            PeerAddr => '192.168.0.2', 
                            PeerPort => 1850, 
                            Proto    => 'tcp', 
                            Type     => SOCK_STREAM
   ) || die "Can't connect to 192.168.0.2:1850 : $!\n"; 

$lsn2 = IO::Socket::INET->new(
                            PeerAddr => '192.168.0.2', 
                            PeerPort = >1852, 
                            Proto    => 'tcp', 
                            Type     => SOCK_STREAM
   ) || die "Can't connect to 192.168.0.2:1852 : $!\n";
```

then, I want to read and write data to both sockets, so the sequence is:

```
1. $lsn1->print(msg1);  send message 1 to server from $lsn1.
2. $line = <$lsn2>;     receive message 2 from server from $lsn2.
3. $lsn2->print(msg3);  send message 3 to server from $lsn2.
4. $lsn2->print(msg4);  send message 4 to server from $lsn2.
5. $line = <$lsn2>;     receive message 5 from server. But it is all zeros! However I can 
                        see the data on wireshark.
```

everything is fine until step 5. After the server side receive my message4 and send back 
msg5 which is supposed to be capture by `$line = <$lsn2>`, instead of capture meaningful value it capture all 0s'. I used wireshark to see what happened, a RST ACK from my side was send after the server send me msg5.

A function in server received msg4 and send back msg5 immediately. If I get rid of the sending of msg4 in that function, what follows the sending of msg5 is `FIN ACK`.

Can anyone tell me why `RST ACK` is happening? Can a perl script opens up two sockets and read and write like I did.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "all zeros"? Do you get an empty string, undef, or actually a bunch of zeroes?

Comment: "all zeros" means the string that I used to store incoming message is empty. I see all zeros because I pack the string into character array.

Comment: Not sure about what does $! and $^E does in perl. I am relative new to perl. But I did print $! and $^E, give me nothing.

Comment: RST ACK usually means port close. But I did not close my port.

Comment: RST-ACK is more "your data is not wanted here, the port is closed". I'd be tempted to track the behaviour of such a program with "strace -eclose,network perl {script}" if your platform supports this. Somehow, your program closed $lsn2 somewhere between line 2 and 5, which would explains that when the expected packet arrives, TCP rejects it, and when you try to read your socket, you don't get anything.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that you are not completely reading Message 2 leaving some data on the socket (line feed, null character, etc.).  When you then attempt to read Message 5 you instead read this data and your program terminates before the server actually sends Message 5.

Comment: It is possible. After I create the two sockets, I added $lsn1->autoflush(1) and $lsn2->autoflush(2) to it. I am testing
to see if it is ok now.